# REST API, что лучше, получать данные по отдельности или вместе?

Tags: rest

Делаю мобильное приложение - расписание. Хочу создать фрагмент - поиск с параметрами. Параметры для поиска будут такие: Группа, семестр, учебная неделя. Хочу получить список этих параметров из веб-сервиса и занести в выпадающий список - spinner.

**Как лучше сделать?**:

1. Отправлять запросы для получения каждого параметра отдельно (в данном случае 3 запроса) (асинхронно), и отображать Fragment, только после получения всех ответов
2. Отправлять запросы для получения каждого параметра отдельно (в данном случае 3 запроса) (асинхронно), и отображать их по мере получения, а пока запрос выполняется выводить рядом, например процесс загрузки, рядом с каждым spinner-ом
3. Отправить один запрос на получение всех параметров, а уже на backend уже сформировать большой json.

Что лучше выполнить несколько мелких запросов, или 1 большой?

Comment: мое субъективное мнение - клиентскую машину не стоит задуривать => считаю что 3 вариан лучший

Comment: А нужны ли эти параметры по отдельности в принципе? Если нет, то очевидно 3 вариант. Если да, то возможны варианты. Хотя я подозреваю, что семестров бывает два, а недель не больше 20, так что если не экономить на спичках, то нет смысла выделять их в отдельный запрос. И вообще, надо ли их запрашивать или можно вычислить на клиенте по календарю?

Comment: Идеологически верно - получать тремя. По скорости - один. Люди задались таким же вопросом как вы и придумали GraphQL. Который как бы прослойка: вы запрашиваете с клиента один раз: "дай мне группы + семестр + недели". GraphQL получает такой запрос и разбивает на три, которые могут идти в совершенно разные системы. Потом объединяет и возвращает один. https://habr.com/ru/post/326986/

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Ну будет еще отдельно расписание для преподов, там параметры ФИО, семестр, учебные недели. Расписание как бы будет 3 видов (на день, на неделю, на семестр). Также предполагается, что можно будет выбрать кабинет и дату и посмотреть, есть ли дисциплины в это время.

Comment: @TotalPusher у меня backend на PHP (Slim), а как я понял ваша библиотека для JS

Comment: Можно ещё на JSON RPC посмотреть https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#batch

Comment: Ах да, расписание перед отображением будет закидываться во встроенную субд на мобилке

Comment: @danilshik, это концепция, не привязанная к конкретной реализации. Не можете по тем или иным причинам поставить готовую прослойку на JS, напишите свою либу. Под слим, не слим, не важно, это концепция.

Comment: @TotalPusher я просто не понимаю причины для использования этой концепции, если я точно также могу просто вызвать метод backend с мобилки, который сформирует совокупной json и отправит обратно на мобилку. Вопрос был как лучше сделать, из - за отсутствия опыта я не могу точно знать, что лучше для серверной части, больше мельких запросов или лучше 1 более крупный